# Compare two dataframes after group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe df1 as

```
  Userid        timestamp      pnl_of_fills variation                                         
    111       1.643955e+09         20.00       bad
    122       1.643955e+09          2.67      good
    221       1.643955e+09          3.33      good
    2735      1.643955e+09          6.60      good
    31124243  1.643955e+09         40.00       bad
```

which was created with groupby Userid in pandas dataframe.

and df2 as

```
   Userid
  
0    111
1    122
2    221
3    2735
4    111
```

I need new dataframe with combine df1 and df2 as df3

df3 like

```
   Userid  pnl_of_fills  Variation 
  
0    111    20.00         bad
1    122    2.67         good
2    221    3.33         good
3    2735    6.60        good 
4.   111    20.00         bad
```

Have tried multiple approaches and didnt find anything useful.

Basically for every value of df2 column, the df1 values needs to be updated.

Comment: would `df1.merge(df2)` work?

Comment: No, on df1 the index is user id.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_on='Userid')`? or `df1.join(df2.set_index('Userid'))` or `df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='Userid')`

Comment: Yes its working..

Comment: Could you please explain how does this work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your 2 dataframes:

```
>>> df1
             timestamp  pnl_of_fills variation
Userid                                        
111       1.643955e+09         20.00       bad
122       1.643955e+09          2.67      good
221       1.643955e+09          3.33      good
2735      1.643955e+09          6.60      good
31124243  1.643955e+09         40.00       bad

>>> df2
   Userid  Dummy
0     111     11
1     122     21
2     221     31
3    2735     41
4     111     51
```

You want to merge them on `Userid`: the problem here is for the first dataframe, `Userid` is the index rather than for the second `Userid` is a column so you need some extra options to use with `merge`:

```
# Merge with index of df1 and column on df2
>>> df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_on='Userid')
      timestamp  pnl_of_fills variation  Userid  Dummy
0  1.643955e+09         20.00       bad     111     11
4  1.643955e+09         20.00       bad     111     51
1  1.643955e+09          2.67      good     122     21
2  1.643955e+09          3.33      good     221     31
3  1.643955e+09          6.60      good    2735     41

# Merge both on columns because you reset index of df1
>>> df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='Userid') 
      timestamp  pnl_of_fills variation  Userid  Dummy
0  1.643955e+09         20.00       bad     111     11
4  1.643955e+09         20.00       bad     111     51
1  1.643955e+09          2.67      good     122     21
2  1.643955e+09          3.33      good     221     31
3  1.643955e+09          6.60      good    2735     41

# Light merge with join based on index of both dataframes
>>> df1.join(df2.set_index('Userid'))
             timestamp  pnl_of_fills variation  Dummy
Userid                                               
111       1.643955e+09         20.00       bad   11.0
111       1.643955e+09         20.00       bad   51.0
122       1.643955e+09          2.67      good   21.0
221       1.643955e+09          3.33      good   31.0
2735      1.643955e+09          6.60      good   41.0
31124243  1.643955e+09         40.00       bad    NaN
```

You can get more information about merge: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)